# Reading output from parent process using Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to write a python script that will read all output of other scripts and save it to a log file. This is my simple test that doesn't work.

```
#parent.py
def writer():
    i = 10
    while i:
        print(i)
        i -= 1

print('Start of parent process \n')
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'reader.py'], stdin=sys.stdout)
print('Start of writer')
writer()
```

```
#reader.py
def reader():
    count = 10
    log = open('log', 'w')
    while count:
        print(f'count = {count}')
        i = input()
        print(i)
        log.write(i)
        count -= 1
    log.close()

print('Second process started')
reader()
print('Second process finish')
```

I need to set the input of the child process, but not send over some channels. I already have few scripts, they use simple `echo` for printing, and my reader should log that.

Comment: In what way "it doesn't work", could you be more specific?

Comment: By the way at the end of `parent.py` you need to `process.wait()` to wait until the subprocess is fully executed. Perhaps without it `sys.stdout` might be cut off midway

Comment: you need to add some sleeping time in your reader.py , else it wil just iterate over the counter as fast as possible, close and exit

Comment: `stdin=sys.stdout` is definitely wrong, but it's not really clear what you expect to happen here. If you want the child to read the parent's standard output, you have to close standard output in the parent and reconnect it to the child's standard input.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, i get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ostapludin/PycharmProjects/LogReader/reader.py", line 34, in <module>
    reader()
  File "/home/ostapludin/PycharmProjects/LogReader/reader.py", line 25, in reader
    i = input()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor```

Comment: @tripleee how can I do that?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I need redirect all output from parent process to child input

Comment: It should not be too hard to figure out from documentation and examples, but I'm wondering about the architectural soundness of this. Somehow it would feel less weird to reverse the roles of parent and child. I hope you are aware that the `logging` module offers quite similar functionality out of the box?